# Where can I find Game Theory-inspired games?

Tags: game-theory

I like the idea of simple games that give players a lot of flexibility in strategy, like [Prisoner's Dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner%27s_dilemma), but something people would actually play for fun. So far, I've managed to find [Pass the Pigs](http://www.passthepigs.com/), a dice game, and [Dominion](http://www.riograndegames.com/games.html?id=278), a card game. What other games have endless strategies to try out, yet involve really simple rulesets?

Sorry if this is off-topic. I didn't know where else to post this.

Comment: The title and the body seem to ask very different questions.

Comment: How would you retitle my post?

Comment: I don't know, but the body of the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with game theory.

Comment: Having two alternatives to choose from counts as "a lot of flexibility"?

Answer (score 1):

Some combinatorial games:

- [Combinatorial Games I: the world of piles of stones](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-games1)
- [Combinatorial Games II: different moves for left and right](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-partizan1)
- [Towards a theory for combinatorial games](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-games5)